# Thread completion in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I have some kotlin code like the following in an android app:

```
Thread(Runnable {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(100)
        ... do useful work ...
        if (checkCurrentCondition()) {
            ... do final useful work ...
            return
        }
    }
}).start()
```

Here is my question: Is there some way (a callback function or some other mechanism) by which I can know in the main thread, that the background thread above has finished its job?

Answer (score 0):

You may use AsyncTask or ThreadPoolExecutor. AsyncTask has the onPostExecute() method using which you can get the execution result right into UI Thread and do your job after. Also there is Looper/Handler usages for ThreadPoolExecutor to communicate between UI/Worker threads.

[For detailed information's look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001259/correct-way-to-communicate-the-result-of-a-background-thread-to-the-ui-thread-in)

Comment: Yes I already read about (deprecated) AsyncTask but I was hoping there would be a solution to the problem without using a different API.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in an `Activity`, you could call `runOnUiThread { doWhatever() }` from the `Thread` - it'll hold a reference to the `Activity`, so don't do this in a long-running thread.

If you create a [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) with `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` then you can `post` `Runnable`s to it - basically the same as `runOnUiThread` except you're not holding onto an Activity, and you can do things like delay and cancel those posted messages.

If you already have some looping activity going on (so you can basically check if the thread's completed) then you could do anything from having a boolean `done` flag that the thread sets (make it `@Volatile` so the main thread sees the change) to all the stuff in [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html) like `Future`s and the like. Really depends on what you're doing.

Posting a `Runnable` to the main thread looper is the easiest general way to make a thing happen. But again, if that thread is creating any data in memory that the main thread needs to see, as always you need to handle synchronization, which is its own topic!